# How to edit php files after building angular app

Tags: php, sql, angular

I want to deploy my angular app on 000webhost. I used ng build to build my project and I uploaded my dist files to the file manager of the webhost. However, my website contains php files with credentials and urls linking to folders in the project such as :

`baseUrl:string = "http://localhost/lfsa-db/php";`

`return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/register.php', { first_name,last_name,father_name})`

My dist files are all .js with the index.html. How can I edit these lines of code ? They were in a .php file before building the project.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to where your files are stored, make changes to those files and re compile your app / refresh the page. When you upload your files to 000webhost you should be able to make changes to them. If you can't, make changes to your angular app locally and re upload the files.

Hope this answers your question.

This is just my personal preference but I would use a git hub repo and deploy that. Using github will allow you to make commits to your branches and your web app will pull from the git hub, easy way to make changes after deploying.

When using webhosting software linking to a github gives you more control, at least in my opinion.